# a problem on composition of functions

Tags: functions

Let $f \colon A \to A$ be a function such that $f \circ f=f$.  If $f$ is one-to-one then prove that $f$ is also onto.

I know in my head that the func. $f$ is $f(x)=x$, but I can't develop a proof for the above statement.

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried?

Comment: Don't try to prove what is the f function. I think that would be much harder than going through the definitions of one-to-one and onto. You can assume you have the one-to-one property and you use the "fof=f" equality somehow (possibly with another thoerem?) to result to the definition of onto.

Comment: thank you.. got it..

Comment: What are the definitions?  What does it mean to be onto?

Comment: onto means that for a function from set A to set B every element in set B has a pre image in A . i.e. f(x) = y for every y in B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I like about this problem is that it places no restriction on the carinality  $A$; its conclusion binds for some *very large sets indeed*.

Suppose $f$ is not surjective, and let

$B = f(A) \tag 1$

be the image of $A$ under $f$; since

$f \circ f = f, \tag 2$

it is clear that every element of $B$ is fixed under $f$, for

$b \in B \Longrightarrow \exists c \in A, \; b = f(c) \Longrightarrow f(b) = f(f(c)) = f(c) = b; \tag 3$

furthermore, for $c \in A$,

$f(c) = c \Longrightarrow c \in B; \tag 4$

thus $B$ is *precisely* the set of fixed points of $f$.

We have assumed $f$ not surjective; then by the above we have

$B \subsetneq A, \tag 5$

which implies

$\exists a \in A \setminus B; \tag 6$

if

$b = f(a) \in B, \tag 7$

then

$f(b) = f(f(a)) = f(a) = b; \tag 8$

we note

$B \ni b \ne a \in A \setminus B, \tag 9$

which contradicts the given hypothesis that $f$ *is* an injective map.  Thus $f$ is in fact surjective.

Answer (score 0):

We know
$f\circ f=f$ so $f([f(x)]) =f (x)$.

Comparing both sides, which shows $[f (x)] = x$ (since $f$ is one-to-one)
so for all $x$ in codomain of $f$ there is an $x$ in domain such that $f(x) = x$ .. so it is onto.. yay...

i see someone downvoted the question

if you feel its a dumb question please know I'm still in school learning relations and functions ! :)

Comment: Questions get marked down or voted to close when they don't show enough initiative.  To do that, this attempt should be included as part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in A$. Let $y=f(x).$ Then $f(y) = f(f(x)) = (f \circ f) (x) = f(x)$ $\implies y=x,$ if $f$ was assumed to be injective. So if $f$ was injective then $f(x)=x,$ for all $x \in A.$ So $f$ is the identity map on $A.$ But then $f$ is clearly surjective, as claimed.

**QED**